# Change specific cell color depending on it's data

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a `datagrid view` that is connected to an access database there is a column called `Status`. 
I want when any cell in that column changed to ready the background color of this cell changes to green and if not ready changes to red.

Suggestions?

Comment: you can do this on datagrid's `fetchrowStyle` event

Answer (score 1):

On `DataBound` function of grid you can check your cell condition and color the cell.

Example:

```
protected void grd_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow GR in grd.Rows)
    {
        //Here run loop on your rows and check value of cell of column name Status 
        GR.Cells[index of cell].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
    }
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on `RowDataBound` event of the grid view as

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Check the status here
            if (status == "ready")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```